# Existence of a Borel probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $X$ be a separable metric space. Denote by $B_q(x)$ the open ball of radius $q>0$ and center $x \in X$. Also, let $\mathscr{B}$ be the (Borel)-$\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets.

> Is it true that there exists a probability measure $\mu: \mathscr{B} \to [0,1]$ such that $\mu(B_q(x))>0$ for all $x \in X$ and $q>0$?

Equivalently, I am asking whether a strictly positive Borel probability measure necessarily exists; probably there is an obvious answer that I am missing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\mu=\sum_{k\geq 1} \delta_{x_k}/2^k$, where $(x_k)$ is a countable dense set.

Comment: ... when infinite and $\frac{1}{|X|}\sum_{x\in X}\delta_x$ for the finite case.

Comment: @Peyton Absolutely!